# Change detection between two Landsat scenes?

Tags: qgis, raster, remote-sensing, landsat, change-detection

I want to do time series analysis and find change in NDVI. I have rasters where each pixel is represented by some value at a time. Also I have same thing but represented by points.

And I would like to generate new map, with changes. Now Im looking at the transformation matrix and also on this post:
[What is Change Detection and how I can perform such analysis with open source tools?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33402/what-is-change-detection-and-how-i-can-perform-such-analysis-with-open-source-to)

Am I thinking right about it? I would really like try to use something in Rcode ([How to represent trend over time?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52502/how-to-represent-trend-over-time)), but Ive just started to learn it.

Qgis, landsat 30x30m

Comment: Even though the scenes more-or-less overlay they will be slightly different, you will need to georeference one to the other by locations that are clearly distinguishable in both to the *subpixel* to do change detection, otherwise slight differences in pixel alignment will show 'false change'. If it is within your scope resample both to ~50m to minimize cell alignment problems after georeference.

Comment: Raster files are downloaded as product 1 from earth explorer so i think they should be georeferenced

Comment: Yes, they are, but both to their own accuracy. They are not likely to perfectly align to the *subpixel* and any slight variations in where the cell boundaries fall will give spurious results. They need to be matched *exactly* to each other. Then solar reflectance, top of atmosphere...

Comment: OK, I will try resampling them to 50m. Than what? raster1 - raster2, will not give me answers, or?

Comment: Is this what you are after?: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/33402/8104

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of that one @Aaron.

Comment: Yes Aaron, Im aloso working with this. I have it in my question.