# Image recognition between Improved vs Raw Land for city parcels from Aerial with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, geoprocessing, image, aerial-photography

Are there any tools or methods that allow QGIS analyze whether the lots/parcels have been untouched or developed, and return a "1" or "0" to a table or points layer or anything?

I was thinking more into simple shape recognition, like a driveway(2 parallel lines) or a rectangle (dwelling of sorts) or by colors: green/brownish(untouched), silver-ish (developed,) or by a differential of "most of area in one color" and a spot with a "different color".
The lots-layer has an attribute table with areas, id, etc. and overlaid with Google Maps/Bing, etc. (see attached pic)

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Change Detection and how I can perform such analysis with open source tools?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33402/what-is-change-detection-and-how-i-can-perform-such-analysis-with-open-source-to)

Comment: I thought I answered earlier. thank you Saijin_Naib

Comment: Good luck with your analysis!

Comment: Thank you, now I'm running into the problem of obtaining historic aerials haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of different plugins available to do Change Detection within QGIS3, such as [PCA4CD](https://github.com/SMByC/PCA4CD) and [Three-D Change Detection](https://github.com/MonsterCrew/Three_D_Change_Detection).

There are also built-in algorithms such as the SAGA Change Detection algorithm.

You can also perform change detection manually.

Finally, see this question which addresses what you want to do:  [What is Change Detection and how I can perform such analysis with open source tools?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33402/what-is-change-detection-and-how-i-can-perform-such-analysis-with-open-source-to)